# creating a query using a variable

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to have the user specify a file that they want to create a new table from, I recorded a macro creating a query to a file on my desktop.

```
Sub Macro3()
    
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Sheet1", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents(""C:\Users\xxxxxxxxx\Desktop\Book1.xlsx""), null, true)," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Sheet1_Sheet = Source{[Item=""Sheet1"",Kind=""Sheet""]}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Promoted Headers"" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Sheet1_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformCol" & _
        "umnTypes(#""Promoted Headers"",{{""Column1"", type any}, {""Column2"", type any}, {""Column3"", type any}, {""Column4"", type any}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
    
    With WSData.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Sheet1;Extended Properties=""""" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$11")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Sheet1"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

I then want to add a string variable to the above code so the user can select the location of a file.

```
Dim FilePath As String

    FilePath = Application.GetOpenFilename()
```

I have tried the below but keep getting error message "runtime error 1004 - application-defined or object-defined error."
Where am I going wrong?

```
Sub Macro3()
    Dim FilePath As String

    FilePath = Application.GetOpenFilename()
    
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Sheet1", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("" & FilePath & ""), null, true)," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Sheet1_Sheet = Source{[Item=""Sheet1"",Kind=""Sheet""]}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Promoted Headers"" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Sheet1_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformCol" & _
        "umnTypes(#""Promoted Headers"",{{""Column1"", type any}, {""Column2"", type any}, {""Column3"", type any}, {""Column4"", type any}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
    
    With WSData.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Sheet1;Extended Properties=""""" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$11")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Sheet1"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

- The query formula looks like `File.Contents("C:\Users\xxxxxxxxx\Desktop\Book1.xlsx")`.
- The string concatation should be as below. The quotation marker (`"`) in a VBA string should be doubled.

```vb
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Sheet1", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents(""" & FilePath & """), null, true)," & _
        Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Sheet1_Sheet = Source{[Item=""Sheet1"",Kind=""Sheet""]}[Data]," & _
        Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Promoted Headers"" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Sheet1_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true])," & _
        Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformCol" & _
        "umnTypes(#""Promoted Headers"",{{""Column1"", type any}, {""Column2"", type any}, {""Column3"", type any}, {""Column4"", type any}})" & _
        Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
```

- If you think triple quotation markers are difficult to understand, you can use `Chr(34)` to generate a quotation marker.

```vb
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Sheet1", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents(" & Chr(34) & FilePath & Chr(34) & "), null, true)," & _
        Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Sheet1_Sheet = Source{[Item=""Sheet1"",Kind=""Sheet""]}[Data]," & _
        Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Promoted Headers"" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Sheet1_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true])," & _
        Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformCol" & _
        "umnTypes(#""Promoted Headers"",{{""Column1"", type any}, {""Column2"", type any}, {""Column3"", type any}, {""Column4"", type any}})" & _
        Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
```

- Another option is to define the doubled quotation marker as a const.

```vb
    Const D_QUO = """" 
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Sheet1", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents(" & D_QUO & FilePath & D_QUO & "), null, true)," & _
        Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Sheet1_Sheet = Source{[Item=""Sheet1"",Kind=""Sheet""]}[Data]," & _
        Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Promoted Headers"" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Sheet1_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true])," & _
        Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformCol" & _
        "umnTypes(#""Promoted Headers"",{{""Column1"", type any}, {""Column2"", type any}, {""Column3"", type any}, {""Column4"", type any}})" & _
        Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
```